# Foreach em uma ViewBag não está funcionando corretamente

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Dentro desse foreach

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h3 id="subscription-@(item.SubscriptionId)" data-id="@item.SubscriptionId" class="item-accordion result-header">
                        @item.OrderId
                    </h3>
                </td>
                @if (Html.CurrentCustomer().Type == Atma.SND.CSP.SharedContracts.Contracts.Customers.CustomerTypeRequest.Reseller)
                {
                    <td>
                        @item.CustomerEmail
                    </td>
                }

                @foreach(var dominio in ViewBag.Dominio)
                {
                    <td>@dominio.Domain</td>
                }

                <td>
                    <span class="@(item.Status == "Ativa" ? "status-ativo" : "status-preto")">@item.Status</span>
                    <div id="subscription-content-@(item.SubscriptionId)" class="conteudo-item-accordion result-area display-none"></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @foreach (var product in item.Products)
                    {
                        <div>
                            @product
                        </div>
                    }
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Detalhes", "Detail", "Subscription", new { id = item.SubscriptionId }, null)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a class="see-order-details" href="@Url.Action("GetOrderDetail", new {id = item.OrderId})">Ver pedido</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
        </tbody>
```

Eu fiz isso

```
@foreach(var dominio in ViewBag.Dominio)
{
    <td>@dominio.Domain</td>
}
```

Acontece que apenas o primeiro item é impresso na tela e isso deve ser por causa de estar dentro de um foreach. Eu preencho minha ViewBag assim:

```
List<MicrosoftCustomer> lista = new List<MicrosoftCustomer>();
foreach (var item in customers)
{                    
  lista.AddRange(ListaMicrosoftCustomer(item.CustomerMicrosoftId));
}
ViewBag.Dominio = lista;
```

Aqui na Controller estão sendo preenchido corretamente, mas minha lógica está errada no momento de carregar na View. Como eu faço para imprimir corretamente o Domain na minha ViewBag?

A minha Model, a mesma da View

```
public class SearchSubscriptionResponse
    {
        public int SubscriptionId { get; set; }
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public int ResellerId { get; set; }
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public Guid CustomerGuid { get; set; }
        public string CustomerEmail { get; set; }

        public string MicrosoftCustomerId { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public DateTime RenewOn { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public decimal EstimatedMonthlyPriceBRL { get; set; }
        public bool PodeAtivar { get; set; }
        public bool PodeAlterar { get; set; }
        public List<string> Products { get; set; }
    }
```

Aqui pego os MicrosoftCustmer

```
private List<MicrosoftCustomer> ListaMicrosoftCustomer(string microsoftCustomerId)
{
    return _microsoftCustomerService.Table.Where(x => x.Id == microsoftCustomerId).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Tente mudar essa linha ` lista.AddRange(ListaMicrosoftCustomer(item.CustomerMicrosoftId));` para `lista.Add(item.CustomerMicrosoftId);`. Posso estar errado, pois não entendi da aonde vem, ou oque é `ListaMicrosoftCustomer`

Comment: @Matheus, é um método que criei para armazenar os MicrosoftCustomer. Vou editar e postar ele. Editei e postei ele

Comment: Acho que envés de usar `AddRange`, o método `Add`, já seria o suficiente

Comment: @Matheus, acho que a questão toda não está aí, mas sim na forma como se extrai a informação na View. Esse é meu gargalo

Answer (score 1):

Você não especificou o tipo da `ViewBag`.

Mude seu `foreach` para que fique como abaixo:

```
@foreach(var dominio in ViewBag.Dominio as List<MicrosoftCustomer>)
{
    <td>@dominio.Domain</td>
}
```

Verifique também, nesse trecho, se retorna mais de um valor:

```
return _microsoftCustomerService.Table.Where(x => x.Id == microsoftCustomerId).ToList();
```

Pra simplificar na hora de verificar os registros mude ele pra que fique assim:

```
private List<MicrosoftCustomer> ListaMicrosoftCustomer(string microsoftCustomerId)
{
    var result = _microsoftCustomerService.Table.Where(x => x.Id == microsoftCustomerId).ToList();
    return result;
}
```

Coloque um **breakpoint** na primeira linha do método e/ou coloque um **Watch** no `var result`e confira o retorno da consulta.

Comment: Ela não retorna um valor apenas um valor, retorna uma lista de valores da forma que eu fiz. MicrosoftCustomerId nesse contexto não é uma PK, mas creio que o problema é que a ViewBag está dentro de um foreach também, acho que pode ser isso, mas estou mudando a abordagem. Criei uma outra propriedade dentro da Model da tela e vou já trazer preenchida, acho que isso seria melhor

Comment: @pnet, editei a resposta, seu viewbag não estava fazendo o cast, ele é um dynamic e no foreach ele não reconheceu como um array para poder percorrer.